# Numerical computation of Lyapunov exponent

Tags: differential-equations, complex-systems

I'm trying to compute the Lyapunov exponent for a smooth continuous time dynamical system(say, $\dot{\bar{x}} = f(\bar x)$). I using the QR decomposition method. Here are the steps that I follow.

1. Choose some initial condition in the basin of the attractor. Call this $\bar v_0$. And have a blob (hypersphere, $U$) of unit radii around $\bar v_{0}$.
2. Iterate one time-step to get $\bar v_{1}$. The blob evolves as $U_{1} = D\bar f(\bar v_{0})\cdot U$. $D\bar{f}(\bar v_{0})$ being the Jacobian matrix.
3. Do a QR decomposition of $U_{1}$. $R$'s diag elements gives me the expansion/contraction rate. Store these lengths (in say J). And $Q$ is my new $U$.
4. Continue this process for say $n$ times.

The Lyapunov exponent(s) is given by, $\lambda = \frac1{k \cdot dt} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log |J_i|$. $dt$ is the time-step of the integrator.

I'm using this procedure to compute the Lyapunov exponent for the Lorenz system as a check. But unortunately this is not working. Is there anything wrong with the steps of the algorithm?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: These may be useful: https://carretero.sdsu.edu/teaching/M-638/lectures/ProgTheorPhys_1990-Geist-875-93.pdf , https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167278996002163 , http://www.math.ualberta.ca/ijnamb/Volume-1-2010/No-2-10/2010-02-02.pdf .

Comment: @stafusa: Thanks for your reference. I had gone through them before. The problem is that with the above algo I cannot reproduce the expected Lyapunov exponents of say the Lorenz system.

Comment: So you get numbers that seem to make sense, but are different from those of the literature?

Comment: @stafusa: No. They make no sense. For the canonical Lorenz system with sigma = 10, r = 28, b = 8/3, I get all +ve exponents! Time-step was 0.01, and # of iterations was 10^3. Also the initial point was chosen on the attractor itself.

Comment: The only thing I notice, is that in the simple Gram-Schmidt method that I used to use for calculating LEs, vectors get normalized at every iteration, while you don't list such a step - but then I don't see them in quick look at the references either. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with their methods, I guess I can't be of much help here.

Comment: @stafusa: The GSO procedure gives me Q and R. Q's form an ONB, so they are normalized. R's diag elements contains the expansion/contraction which is of importance. So typically for one iteration the Lyapunov exponent is $\log(R_{ii})$. And I do $n$ such iterations and perform an average.

Comment: Hmm... It makes sense. It might then be that the method is correct, but you have a bug in your code - in which case it's off topic here, but you could try some other SE, if you're willing to share your code.

Comment: @stafusa: Yes sure. Which SE should I try? Any pointers?

Comment: Sure. The first SE that comes to mind is [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) and the original [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), there are as well as a few specific-language ones, such as for [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @stafusa: Thanks a ton! Already posted!

Comment: I hope you do not apply the "basic" Gram-Schmidt algorithm? The stability of this algorithm is not acceptable. What is your rate of reorthogonalizations? What is your abort criteria? Commonly, this should be a "static state", for instance the ergodic attractor. If you are familiar with german, the german wikipedia article addresses this issue with reference to Gram-Schmidt vectors for multidimensional systems: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljapunow-Exponent